# Function arguments format in TSLint

Tags: typescript, code-formatting, tslint

Let's say we have a constructor:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    // Some code here
}
```

At some point developer decides to add a new parameter in this way:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef,
            private config: Config) {
    // Some code here
}
```

Is there a way to prevent this and force developers to use either this format:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private config: Config) {
    // Some code here
}
```

either this format:

```
constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private config: Config,
) {
    // Some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such rule at the moment. If you really want to enforce this rule you might have to write your own [custom one](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We decided to go with https://github.com/prettier/prettier. It automatically reformats code.